# Very Cheap Camera Module or Lens for Raspberry Pi

Tags: camera, modules

I have been looking around for any cheap (less than $7) alternative to the official Rasberry Pi camera module. Is there any extremely cheap camera module/feature/extension available for Rasberry Pi?

The goal is to have an array of 25+ camera modules that will asynchronously capture pictures. The quality of the camera **does not** have to be up to par as the official Rasberry Pi module, even a low quality image would be ok.

Thanks

Comment: The goal is to have.....? You are hoping to find a camera that is less than 1/3rd the price of the Pi Cam with more features than the Pi cam they may not be a realistic expectation.

Comment: oops sorry I think the rest got cut off, I will make it clearer

Comment: you want to connect 25 cameras to one pi?

Comment: The cheapest usable cameras would be some kind of *really* bad USB webcam. [Ebay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/USB-30M-Mega-Pixel-Webcam-Video-Camera-Web-Cam-For-PC-Laptop-Notebook-Clip-WY-/262367194305?hash=item3d164dacc1:g:SZUAAOSwsN9XAOdB) is likely to be a good source. The only application for 25 simultaneous cameras I can think of is a bullet time rig - you'll never pull that off like this. Worth a look at [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/frozen-pi-bullet-time-photography-with-the-raspberry-pi/).

Comment: @goobering thank you for that post, yes thats the kind of idea I have but the cameras are to take photos asynchronously of a certain chemical reaction in different wells. Each well will require one camera. I hope though that I would not need 48 rasberry pi's as used in the bullet time rig

Comment: And @edo1 yes, I was wondering if it is even possible to daisy chain that many cameras to one pi. What would be the minimum number I might need?

Comment: If cost is a major driver then perhaps you should consider a more budget-friendly platform? I *think* you could put together something that works using a heap of [ESP8266s](http://goo.gl/eu1PiK) and [OV7670](http://goo.gl/br9RLO) camera modules. Then use a Pi Zero or A+ with WiFi adapter to co-ordinate everything and save the outputs. *Very* limited timing precision, but it's going to be cheap. [This](http://www.arducam.com/tag/arducam-esp8266/) tutorial and [these](https://github.com/ArduCAM/Arduino/tree/master/ArduCAM/examples) examples look promising.

Comment: Those camera modules are kinda what I am looking for since they are pretty cheap... do you think I could manage that many (25+) modules with a single Pi or I would need a few more (or would I need to implement an Arduino, A+ etc.). I am currently in the design phase of my project and I just wanted to get a rough idea of the overall setup. Thanks again!

Comment: Each one of those cameras needs its own brain (hence the ESP8266 modules, which are effectively Wi-Fi arduinos). You could control 25 ESP8266s over Wi-Fi, from a pi, with no issues. You won't be able to connect 25 camera modules directly to a single pi however.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are explicitly off-topic: [off-topic](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

You can get one on Aliexpress for under $7, right here:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-raspberry-pi-camera-5mp-pixels-RASPBERRY-PI-CAMERA/32293433078.html

Comment: and [aliexpress under $5](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Raspberry-Pi-Camera-Module-China-Version-FZ0364-Free-Shipping-Dropshipping/1752058692.html).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, eBay has this [OV5647 5MP Camera OV5647 Camera Module for Raspberry Pi A/B+/2 Model B W/ Cable](https://www.ebay.com/itm/OV5647-5MP-Camera-OV5647-Camera-Module-for-Raspberry-Pi-A-B-2-Model-B-W-Cable/191823838867) (1080p) US $3.97 + Free S/H and this [New USB Camera for Raspberry Pi 2 Model B/B+/A+ Not Require Drivers HOT](https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-USB-Camera-for-Raspberry-Pi-2-Model-B-B-A-Not-Require-Drivers-HOT/283211344896) (640x480 video resolution) US $3.99 + Free S/H. According to both specs, the former has a much better video resolution, at least 4x the later, AFAICT. So, I certainly will get the former if I need one.